# Setting up microsoft visual studio code for c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Ok guys so here is my problem. I am really just a begginer in programming, especially in c++ and all of the vids and research that I did suggests that ms visual code is the best and therefore I really wanna start using it. The problem is that due to the fact that I am a complete newbie, I can't really figure out how  to modify the paths etc in order to make the compiler work. I would really like your help , the best would be to provide me with the correct .json files(tasks,properties,launch), or a copy of the code, in order to make it work. I would also like to add the I've installed mingw and basically every other similar program (don't know why) all installed in the default paths the installation process suggests. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Visual Studio is better for C++ development than Visual Studio Code. Especially for beginners. Everything works out of the box. I suggest you switch to Visual Studio.  From what I saw Visual Studio Code is more targeted at web development and is more of an advanced editor than a full IDE (I could be wrong, I am not using it that much). And yeah... the naming of these two products could be confusing. I don't understand the rationale, especially since they are both from the same company.

Comment: Visual Studio Code for linux. Are you using Windows or Linux? Try Visual Studio if you using windows

Comment: Have you already followed this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp ?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking lol, when you download IDE you are using it usually have Compiler built in, pretty sure VS has one. I'm using CodeBlocks and for newbies it is the best one, atleast for me who is still newbie